# Isometric stratification preserves volume?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, isometries

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ be a non-empty compact subset let $f:K \to K$ be Lipschitz and surjective.  If, moreover, $f$ is an isometry then clearly $f$ preserves the Lebesgue measure of $K$.

I consider the following generalization:
Let, $\{K_i\}_i$ be a collection of mutually-disjoint compact subsets of $K$ containing at-least two points, and for which $\bigcup_i K_i =K$ as a set, and let $f:K\to K$ be a Lipschitz function satisfying
$$
f|_{K_i} \mbox{ is an isometry}
$$
Intuition: *So the isometry property of $f$ is stratified to each $K_i$*

Does $f$ preserve the Lebesgue measure of $K$?

Comment: Obviously not, e.g., take $K_i$ to be singletons.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, $K_i$ should have at-least two points so that the isometry property means something..

Comment: You now excluded singletons, but there are still trivial counterexamples of the same flavour with $K_i$ not singletons (and infinite). [BTW you removed the assumption "is an isometry"after "$f|_{K_i}$" so the sentence is incomplete]

Comment: You still haven't addressed this. Take in $\mathbf{R}^2$ the diagonal matrix $(1,1/2)$ and take $K_i$ to be contained in horizontal lines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a result that may come  close to what you want. As you know, if $(M_i,g_i)$, $i=0,1$  are two Riemann  manifolds and $F:M_0\to M_1$ is an isometry, i.e., diffeomorphism such that $F^*g_1=g_0$, then  the two manifolds have the same metric volumes,  same curvatures etc.

A similar result holds  for singular spaces. To better appreciate the following abstract definition consider the following  simple experiment.  Take  two sheets of paper, of identical sizes. Then crumple one of them.

[image]

The resulting crumpled  sheet   is isometric with the unfolded sheet in the sense that there exists an obvious piecewise linear homeomorphism between them  that sends a curve one one sheet to a curve one the other sheet of equal  length.

You can imagine more complicated situations by opening a  book to see its pages  fanning out, glued along the book's  spine. This is obviously not a manifold and if you fold some sheets you obtain a new space isometric to the original.

Now for the abstract definition. The appropriate category of spaces to work with are the compact subanalytic subsets  of $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ of some $\bR^n$; see  [Sec. 2.1 of these notes](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/conormal_curv.pdf) for  the exact meaning of subanalytic.

A *subanalytic isometry* between  two compact subanalytic  sets $X_0, X_1$ is a subanalytic homeormorphism $F:X_0\to X_1$ such that, for any subanalytic curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to X_0$ ($\gamma$ subanalytic, continuous injective map) the curve $F\circ \gamma$  has the same length as $\gamma$.
We say that two compact  subanalytic  sets $X_i\subset \bR^{n_i}$, $i=0,1$ are *intrinsically isometric* if there exists a  subanalytic isometry between them.

Two  intrinsically isometric subanalytic sets $X_0,X_1$  have the same dimension  and
$$
\mu_m(X_0= \mu_m(X_1),\;\;m=\dim X_0=\dim X_1.
$$
Above,  $\mu_m$ denotes the $m$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

This is a special case of a theorem of J. Fu that shows  much more. More precisely
$$\mu_k(X_0)=\mu_k(X_1),\;\;\forall k=0,1,\dotsc, m,
$$
where $\mu_k$ denotes the $k$-dimensional curvature measure of a compact subnalytic subsets. For example $\mu_0$ is the Euler characteristic. If $X\subset \bR^n$ is an $m$-dimensional  smooth subanalytic manifold,  then $\mu_{m-2}(X)$ m is, up to a universal  multiplicative constant, the integral  over $X$ of the scalar curvature of the induced  metric.  In this case these curvature measures appear in the tube formula $c=n-m$,  $\newcommand{\bT}{\mathbb{T}}$
$$
{\rm vol}_n\big(\bT_r(X)\big)= \mu_m(X)\omega_c r^c+ \mu_{m-2}(X)\omega_{c+2}r^{c+2}+ \cdots,\;\;r\ll 1,
$$
where $\omega_d$ denotes the Euclidean volume of the 
 unit $d$-dimensional  ball and $\bT_r(X)$ is tube of radius $r$ around $X$
$$
\bT_r(X)=\big\{ x\in \bR^n;\;\;{\rm dist}(x,X)\leq r\big\}.
$$
For more details  and a proof of Fu's result see [the same notes as above](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/conormal_curv.pdf). Fu's theorem is in Section 4.5